# D3.js Understanding pie-chart animation

Tags: animation, d3.js, pie-chart

I am following [Mike Bostock's D3 animated pie-chart update](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) and there are some parts of the code I cannot understand. Hope someone can help figuring them out:

```
var path = svg.datum(data).selectAll("path")
  .data(pie)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial angles
```

My issue here is with the last line. I have seen this in different tutorials. I wonder where is the initial angle stored? If I look at the objects in my pie(dataset) array, I do not see the the `_current` entry.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
d3.select("input[value=\"oranges\"]").property("checked", true).each(change);
}, 2000);
```

What does this do? Is it necessary to block the update animation in case the user updates it again before the animation has completed (i.e. by clicking on the other input before 2000 ms)?

```
function change() {
var value = this.value; //(1)
clearTimeout(timeout); //(2)
pie.value(function(d) { return d[value]; }); // change the value function (3)
path = path.data(pie); // compute the new angles
path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs
}
```

(I added the numbers to refer to each line more easily)
(1) Does this stores the datum's value as `value`?
(2) This should be connected to the `timeout` variable above, right?
(3) Would it be the same to write `d.value` instead of `d[value]`? Since my data structure is different that the one used in the tutorial, I will come back to this shortly.

```
function type(d) {
 d.apples = +d.apples;
 d.oranges = +d.oranges;
 return d;
}
```

I do not get this at all, `type` is used also the the data loading function but I cannot understand the logic nor the syntax. I suspect that it has to do with "adapting" the data and drawing functions to the "type" (i.e. input) selected by the user, but this is as far as I can get.
As regards my own chart, this is (part of) the data I intend to use:

```
[
{
"key":"amministrazione",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":404571081,
"val2013":374545999
},
{
"key":"sociale",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":235251679,
"val2013":258973653
},
{
"key":"territorio e ambiente",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":286164667,
"val2013":274949400
},
{
"key":"viabilità e trasporti",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":144185664,
"val2013":140619534
},
{
"key":"istruzione",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":168774925,
"val2013":170016208
}
]
```

When the user clicks on the input (i.e. a radio button) I want to the change the year displayed (from `val2015` to `val2013` and vice-versa). In (3) above the `pie.value` is changed. I would make a function for each year that changes `pie.value` to the respective `d.data.valXX` entry. I guess Mike made his code more effective by relating the change in `pie.value` to the input clicked by the user. Is this what the `type` function is for?

Comment: `type(d)` ensures that you convert each of the object's values to a float. If d.apples was a string, where `apple: "3"`, `+d.apple` would turn that string to a float — to the number 3.

Comment: Oh ok that it's even simpler than I thought. Though it makes the rest of the code more unclear. For example, how does the change function point to the right 'd[value]' depending on the input clicked?

Comment: It's called as soon as the data is loaded, so it precedes anything else. As soon as you load the data in, it gets converted to floats.

Comment: Ok. My problem is another, though. In the example the user can choose to see a pie chart referring to either apples or oranges. My question on the `change()` function - i.e. how does the function handle the click event by changing the `pie.value` function to display the values corresponding to the fruit chosen? (this is done at point (3) in the code but.. how?)